# Liferay 6.2 search portlet configuration for all pages

Tags: liferay, liferay-hook

i've implemented an hook for liferay CE 6.2GA4 that adds a search field inside the dockbar, using `<liferay-ui:search />` tag inside the `view_user_panel.jspf` file.

After that i've deployed the standard search portlet and implemented a custom configuration for facet search, adding my custom entities etc..
If i use the search portlet inside the dockbar IN my HOME (with also the original portlet configured) all is working good, but using the search in the dockbar in any OTHER page then the portal uses the standard configuration when showing the result.

Is there a way to set a global configuration (at last for all site pages) for search portlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember I fall in the same issue time ago.

Please check if this way resolves the situation: create an hidden page, put it search portlet inside it, configure it as you want.

Consider the standard search portlet has `<preferences-owned-by-group>true</preferences-owned-by-group>`.

Let me know.

Comment: this worked, but also it's required to add <preferences-unique-per-layout>false</preferences-unique-per-layout> tag inside the liferay-portlet.xml that defines the portlet 3 (search portlet). The file can be find inside tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF